# GridView footer not displaying data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm using ASP.NET (VB.NET) with SQL-Server-2012.

I'm using a GridView to display data in table called `project_items`.

I added a FooterTemplate so that I could display the total amount of all the records in a column.

This is what I did:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"  Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_name" HeaderText="Item" SortExpression="item_name" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_cost" HeaderText="Cost (inc. VAT)" SortExpression="item_cost" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="item_quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="item_quantity" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Total (inc. VAT)">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="TextBox3" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("item_quantity")) * Convert.ToDouble(Eval("item_cost"))%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" />
                                     </FooterTemplate>  
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" />
                                     </FooterTemplate>  
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                        </asp:GridView>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStringDb1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 
      items.item_name, items.item_cost, project_items.item_quantity
    FROM items
    INNER JOIN project_items ON items.item_id = project_items.item_id
    WHERE project_items.project_id = @parameter">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="parameter" SessionField="ProjectID" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

VB.NET Code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data



Partial Class ProjectReport
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private myTotal As Decimal = 0



    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim ProjectID = Session("project_id")
        Session("ProjectID") = ProjectID

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            BindData()
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub BindData()

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim query As New SqlCommand("SELECT Items.item_name, Items.item_cost, project_items.item_quantity FROM Items INNER JOIN project_items ON items.item_id = project_items.item_id WHERE project_items.project_id = @parameter", conn)

        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", Convert.ToInt32(Session("ProjectID")))

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(query)

        da.SelectCommand = query

        Dim table As New DataTable()


        da.Fill(table)

        grdItems.DataSource = table
        grdItems.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub grdItems_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim lblPrice As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice"), Label)

            Dim price As Double = CDec(lblPrice.Text)
            myTotal += price

        End If

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            Dim lblTotalPrice As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice"), Label)
            lblTotalPrice.Text = myTotal.ToString()

        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

[image]

The problem is that the footer is not displaying the total amount (or any values).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your row data bound isn't quite right.

The RowDataBound gets fired for every row. So when you're checking a DataRow you're starting off with a Total of 0. This is getting reset on every call. So when you're finally around to the Footer row Total is still 0.

Instead, do the following:

Declare a private decimal in outside of your page load:

```
Private myTotal As Decimal = 0
```

Then in your databinding add up your totals and store it in `total`

Then use that in your footer. Something like

```
Protected Sub grdItems_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
         Dim rowView As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
         myTotal += (CDec(rowView("item_cost")) * CDec(rowView("item_quantity")))

    End If

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        Dim lblTotalPrice As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice"), Label)
        lblTotalPrice.Text = myTotal.ToString()

    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

You don't have a `lblPrice` in your gridview. So if you put a breakpoint at your myTotal += price you're adding 0 to 0.

See code above for different way to get your price.

Comment: I tried as you said and the footer is still empty. What am I missing ? (Updated code in question)

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you. Again, the footer is not being displayed. Is something wrong with my ASP code ?

Comment: the footer IS being displayed; you can see that in your image. What's wrong is that you're trying to add up a figure that doesn't exist. There is no `lblPrice` in your gridview, so it adds zero to `myTotal`

Comment: Try adding some breakpoints in your code so you can see exactly what is being called and what total is being set. Also see the updated code in my answer, it shows you how to get the `item_cost` from your `dataitem`

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand. I added a lblPrice but still nothing is displayed (see updated code)

Comment: You added lblPrice in the footer. How is this going to help? You're not getting the price from the footer, you want to get the price from the actual data row. In your case I assume `item_cost`. Did you look at my updated code in the answer? Stop with the lblPrice for now and copy what I put above.

Comment: Yes I tried it without lblPrice and the amount is still not being displayed.

Comment: Ok, I can't help any more. I've recommended the best way to do this, provided code that should work for you and also recommended that you put breakpoints in your code so you can inspect exactly what is happening.

Comment: Ok you mentioned I need to add the rows in my data binding event which is DataBind() could that be the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried just copying my code after i updated it? have you tried adding breakpoints and inspecting the new code i added, especially the `rowView` ? your answer lays in there..

Comment: Yes I did. myTotal remains 0.

Comment: did you inspect the `rowView` and its properties? I'm out of ideas... this works 100% for me.

Comment: Is it maybe because the sub-total of the items cost (quantity*item_cost) is a template field (i.e. not taken from db table) ?

Comment: Or maybe something with the session

Comment: I doubt anything to do with session. Also in my code i do not look at the template field, I take the cost and qty directly from the item data - which is the data your binding with.