# my gridview footer is not showing the results of calculated columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview

my aspx code is:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Item_id" 
                   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ShowFooter="True" 
                   onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                   <Columns>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                           SortExpression="Item_id">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Item_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert"
                                    Font-Bold="true" BackColor="#0099CC" ForeColor="white" Height="30px" Width="100px" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category_name" SortExpression="Category_name">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbC" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="120px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="item_name" SortExpression="item_name">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbN" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="120px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="unit_price" SortExpression="unit_price">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TbPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("unit_price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("unit_price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>

                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbP" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuantitySelected" 
                           SortExpression="QuantitySelected">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Textbox ID="TbQt" runat="server"   Text='<%# Bind("QuantitySelected") %>'></asp:Textbox>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("QuantitySelected") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbQ" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="Total">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Textbox ID="TbTl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total") %>'></asp:Textbox>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Total") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbT" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Discount" SortExpression="Discount">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Textbox ID="TbD" runat="server"   Text='<%# Bind("Discount") %>'></asp:Textbox>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Discount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbD" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grand_total" SortExpression="Grand_total">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Textbox ID="TbGtl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Grand_total") %>'></asp:Textbox>
                           </ItemTemplate>

                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Grand_total") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                           <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TbG" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px" Font-Bold="true"></asp:TextBox>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width ="100px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
```

my code behind is:
            public partial class ItemPage : System.Web.UI.Page
            {
                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Category_name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbC")).Text;
            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["item_name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbN")).Text;
            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["unit_price"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbP")).Text;
            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["QuantitySelected"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbQ")).Text;

            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Total"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbT")).Text;
            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Discount"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbD")).Text;

            SqlDataSource2.InsertParameters["Grand_total"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TbG")).Text;



        }    




                 double price = 0.0f;
        double quantity = 0.0f;
        double total = 0.0f;
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox tb11 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Tb2");
                TextBox tb12 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("Tb3");
                TextBox tb13 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbPrice");
                TextBox tb14 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbQt");
                TextBox tb15 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbTl");
                TextBox tb16 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbDs");
                TextBox tb17 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbGtl");

                price = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbPrice")).Text);
                quantity = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbQt")).Text);


                total = price * quantity;
                //total += total;
                tb15.Text = total.ToString();

            }

            else
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
                {



                    TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbC");
                    TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbN");
                    TextBox tb3 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbP");
                    TextBox tb4 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbQ");
                    TextBox tb5 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbT");
                    TextBox tb6 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbD");
                    TextBox tb7 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbG");


                    tb5.Text = total.ToString();

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

i hv posted my edit code again. the problem is when i run the page i am getting blank textboxes in my footer. only textbox in "total" column has vales and that too is some vague value.. i have to put values in "price" "quantity" and then click "insert" button to add values into grid along with calculated value in "total" column.. i am still stuck!! plz help!!

Comment: I gave an answer to the same issue here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040961/gridview-footer-not-displaying-data/16041178#16041178 -

Comment: i have gone through your answer. but i am not understanding what format error is there. i have textbox as compared to label in my item templates and footer templates.

Comment: Doesn't matter what they are - the principle is the same. Actually the answer below would be good for you too.

Answer (score 0):

you also need this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

where you do the summation.

Note: the variables need to be declared outside the event handler or they will be zeroed on each iteration.

**EDIT**- zero out the summation variable when `e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header`

**EDIT** Do something like this:

```
double grand_total = 0;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        grand_total = 0;
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        double price    = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbP")).Text);
        double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbQ")).Text);
        double total    = price * quantity ;

        ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbT")).Text = total.ToString();

        grand_total += total;

    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TbT")).Text = grand_total.ToString() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have included the if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow). but again its showing error. its saying input format not correct. in the total' calculation

Comment: well for one - don't take the above code verbatim - it's untested - please correct for syntax and such.  This was more to give you the general premise on how to calculate fields "on the fly"

Comment: i am getting predefined garbage values in my "total" textbox column of footer.?why is that?

Comment: i have posted my edited code. i was able to insert by button click while i was typing values in repective columns. but i want "total" to get calculated and then inserted into grid so i added "rowdatabound" event. help!!

Comment: just to clarify...as you currently have things defined, total only ever contains price*quantity for a SINGLE row.  you have no summation for the "total of totals" e.g. the grand_total.  So what you assign in the footer is actually undefined.

Comment: Also...are you clear that the RowDataBound event is called once for the header, once for each row of bound data, and once for the footer

Comment: This is getting far more involved than a simple summation. I cannot guess which fields are  coming from the database, versus which fields are user supplied, versus which are calculated.  You might be better off being more specific in your initial question.

Comment: i am able to insert the way i wanted. but i am not using "row databound" event... but i finally got the result i wanted

Comment: whew - great - glad you were able to fix it

Comment: ;) but next question aroused the very next moment. :) now i want a text box and a button outside gridview. i want to put the sum of all grand totls in that textbox on button click.. any clue??

Comment: look at my code above and see how i'm calculating the grand_total.  Just populate the textbox with that value in the `DataBound` event or in the button Click event.  Just realize that the grand_total is recalculated on every postback, which may happen each time you click the button if your button control is configured like that.